# using PHP session inside JAVASCRIPT ones ?

Tags: javascript, php, session

this is working :

```
var ts="<?php $auto[0]=$_SESSION['auto'];$auto[1]=1;?>";
```

this doesn't work :

```
var ts="<?php $auto[0]=$_SESSION['auto'];$auto[1]=$_SESSION['auto'];?>";
```

help me

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You are not `echo` anythings, PHP just execute the script in the balista without ever outputing something.

Comment: Define "working" and "doesn't work".  What does this *do*?  And how does it fail?

Comment: if I use the first line I get the results but if use the second one I get error

Comment: You have code which produces an error and you don't even tell us what the error is?

Comment: I get bthis error : function tetser () is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
var o;
    function changementEtat(){
        if(o.readyState==4) {
            var text = o.responseText;
            //alert(text);
            var ts="<?php $auto[0]=$_SESSION['auto'];$auto[1]=$_SESSION['auto'];?>";


        }
    }

    function tester() {
            var abc=3;

            modal.style.display = "none";

            o = new XMLHttpRequest();
            o.open('POST',"ajax.php",true);
            o.onreadystatechange =changementEtat;
            o.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            o.send("tfu="+abc);



        document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML="<?php $table=$tableau->nextTable($table,1,$auto); echo $tableau->tableToString2($table,Null); ?>";
        styler();
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
```